# How to paste 25 letter product key at once

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to paste all 25 letters of a key at once rather than copying pasting each block at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on the form into which you are pasting.

It it were one large text field, you might be able to.  That is assuming the that there is no logic programmed into the form that would break if there were or were not dashes (-).

If the form is broken into 5 fields of 5 characters, it wont work.  That is unless the developer put in logic to detect pasting of more characters than allowed.

I have seen some forms block pasting of keys.  Not entirely sure why, though.

There are *many* reasons it wont work...

You *could* write a program to do this, if you had a large number of keys to fill.

[Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) might also work, depending on the form.